# How to resize image by mainitaining aspect ratio in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have an image with `image.shape=(20,10)`and I want to resize this image so that new image size would be `image.size = 90`.

I want to use `np.resize(image,(new_width, new_height))`, but how can I calculate `new_width` and `new_height`, so that it maintains `aspect_ratio` as same as in original image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you choose which dimension you want to enforce and then you adjust the other one by calculating either `new_width = new_height*aspect_ratio` or `new_height = new_width/aspect_ratio`.

You might want to round those numbers and convert them to `int` too.

Answer (score 0):

The height of your image is 20 and the width is 10, so the height is 2x the width, i.e.

```
h = 2 * w
```

You want your new image to have an area of 90 pixels, and the area (A) is:

```
A = h * w

90 = 2 * w * w

w = sqrt(45)
```

So the sides of your image need to be 6.7 and 13.4

I hope that helps, even if I doubt it will.

Comment: Exactly, after getting idea from Guimoute, did same as your answer. it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple function for finding the new height of an image with width as an input

```
def findHeight(original_width, original_height, new_width):
    area = original_width * original_height
    new_height = area/new_width
    return new_height
```